# Push command not working with Git

Tags: git

I cloned a repository with the clone command successfully.  BUT, I tried to push after commit and I get this error.

> $ git push git@github.com:taraloca/QuitIt.git
>   Permission denied (publickey).
>   fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's a public repo, anyone can clone, however a key is required to push. This key provides authentication, and tells Github that you are allowed to push to that repo.

Instructions located here http://help.github.com/msysgit-key-setup/

Comment: Yep, the error message `Permission denied (publickey)` is indicating that you don't have your authentication key configured correctly (or not at all).